# Is there a way to create left_table, connecting_table, right_table rows in one step using peewee

Tags: python-3.x, database, orm, relationship, peewee

Given the following Models:

```
class LeftTable(Model):
    left_table_col = TextField()

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'left_table'

class RightTable(Model):
    right_table_col = TextField()

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'right_table'

class ConnectingTable(BaseModel):
    con_table_column = TextField()
    from_left = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='left_table')
    to_right  = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='related_to')

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'connecting_table'
        indexes = (
            # Specify a unique multi-column index on from/to-user.
            (('from_left', 'to_right'), True),
        )
```

Is there a way to create the left_table row, connecting_table row and right_table row all in one step in Peewee?

normally I'd just populate left_table, right_table and then adding a row in connecting_table using the respective ids (left_table_id, right_table_id) and additional values.

Programmer looking for a short-cut... go figure.

Comment: Just noticed an error in my example...

```to_right  = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='related_to')```

should be 

```to_right  = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='right_table')```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you question ! Do not hesitate to use the edit button to add additional details and remove errors if needed !

Comment: Also, I'm interested in this question and I have a related question up right now you might be interested in ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404250/peewee-access-an-intermediary-table-easily

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, relational databases don't have any concept of "insert into multiple tables in one operation". For this you have a different primitive: transactions.

So the proper way to do this is:

- Begin a transaction
- Insert into left table, right table, join table.
- Commit